# How to set fontcolor with toggle button in high contrast wpf

Tags: wpf, accessibility, high-contrast

In my app, when the toggle button is checked, I set a color for Foreground like this:

```
 <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/tab.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#0261A5"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        </Trigger>
```

But it is not display well in High Contrast mode, I can set the background as transparent in High Contrast mode, but how to set Foreground to system color?

Comment: Which SystemColor you want to set this to?

Comment: Is there a way to let it auto adapt to the high contrast mode? There're four high contrast mode in high contrast control panel.